# docker-compose can't find services or containers in Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose set up that starts a Rails web application and a PostgreSQL DB container.

Both services start, but I need to run db:seed and db:migrate in the web application container (service = "web").

I try to do this with:

```
docker-compose exec web rails db:seed
```

But it tells me:

```
ERROR: No container found for web_1
```

When I try with docker:

```
docker exec <container-id> rails db:seed
```

Docker does try to execute the command in the container, but it obviously fails, as docker has no knowledge of the PostgreSQL container and can't connect to it to execute the seed comand.

This only appears to be an issue in Docker for Mac. It all works fine in Ubuntu.

I am using Version 1.8.0 of docker-compose and 1.12.1 of docker.

Comment: when it's running what does `docker ps` show ?

Comment: It shows the 2 containers running as normal.

Comment: what's the output, ie container name?

Comment: For the web application, the name is "server_web_1". Using that as the identifier produces the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found the answer. Not sure if this is specific to Docker for Mac, but I didn't have this issue in Ubuntu.

I have 2 terminals running. In the first, I ran

```
docker-compose up
```

to bring up my services.

In the second, I ran:

```
docker-compose exec web rails db:seed
```

To execute the rails command in my web container.

Here's in the thing: in the second terminal, you have to be in the same directory as your docker-compose.yml file. You can't just run your docker-compose commands from anywhere.

When I changed to the correct directory in my 2nd terminal, the exec commands worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `docker-compose run` it generates a random unique name for the running container, you'll have to specify that when using exec.

`$ docker-compose run bot
...`

In another terminal:

`$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
306bd1381f81        rroemhild/errbot    "/app/venv/bin/run.sh"   13 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       3141-3142/tcp       err_bot_run_31
$ docker exec bot whoami
Error response from daemon: No such container: bot
$ docker exec err_bot_run_31 whoami
err`

Comment: That doesn't work. I know it should, but there is something more fundamentally wrong here, that is specific to Docker for Mac.

Comment: I did that using Docker for mac. OSX is 10.12 sierra, ```$ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.1, build 6f9534c``` ```$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7```

Comment: If your docker is behaving erratic compared to my output perhaps you should reinstall/reset using the icon on your OSX finder and try again.

Comment: Also if you look carefully i'm using docker to run exec. Per https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/ : `This is equivalent of docker exec. `. If it works the way you think it should in ubuntu but not OSX file a bug at https://github.com/docker/compose/ . It looks though as though all the things I've found say to specify the container id or name exactly which makes sense per the reference link that it's no diff than `docker exec`